# How to access Iphone address book mobile number which has space in Ios7

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a mobile number in iphone address book look like 0413 588 266

```
ABMutableMultiValueRef phoneno  = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

    NSString *phone;
    if(ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneno) > 0) 
    {
        phone =  (__bridge NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneno, 0);

    }
    NSLog(@"phone%@",phone);
```

When i import that number it gives phone(null) value in IOs7
I do not have any issues with Ios6.any help will be appreciated.thanks in advance.

Comment: negative mark are welcome.give reason for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try this way...
```

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>
#import <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
<ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, retain) ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *contacts;
-(IBAction)btn_press:(id)sender;
@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
-(IBAction)btn_press:(id)sender
{
    contacts = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];

    // Set the delegate.
    [contacts setPeoplePickerDelegate:self];
    [contacts setDisplayedProperties:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonPhoneProperty]]];
    [self presentViewController:contacts animated:YES completion:nil];

}

    #pragma mark - AddressBook Delegate Methods

    -(BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person{
        return YES;
    }


    -(BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier{



NSString *firstName = (__bridge NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);

    ABMutableMultiValueRef phoneno  = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

    NSString *phone;
      phone =  (__bridge NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneno, 0);
    NSLog(@"%@",phone); // Prints 0413588266



  **** NEW Update for Dismiss the Picker*******
 [contacts dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
   return NO:
}
```

**Let me know if you have any problem.**

Comment: Is this helpful to you?

Comment: Sorry but i am not getting you.

Comment: How do i get first name and mobile together?

Comment: it dismiss view when selecting mobile.How do i dismiss pickerview when select firstname?

Comment: Do you mean that if you select any thing then dismiss the picker controller?